# Use javascript to import a json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

Im creating  a website using a json file to store the data to be used on one of the pages, but I am struggling to import the data successfully. Im using repl.it to code in.

So far I've tried:

`var data = require("data.json")` and got `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

and

`<script src="data.json"></script>` `const dta = JSON.parse(data)` and got `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

And Ive looked at other questions and been really confused by them

Im not sure whether this is related but I also get a syntax error in my json file set out like
`data = '[{"foo": "bar"}]'`

How can i fix these errors?

Answer (score 1):

`require` is a Node.js function. It (at the time of writing) does not exist in browsers just yet.
And you never did declare `data` so yes it's not defined.
You can `fetch` the JSON data using the Fetch API:

```js
fetch('/data.json').then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Search up "promises" on MDN for info about the `then`method
To be able to access `data` globally, you can use an `Immediately Invoked Function Expression` (IIFE) with async/await.

```js
(async function() {
const data = await fetch('/data.json').then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => data);
})();
```

Search up "IIFE" on MDN for more info, and `async/await` is a way to consume promises.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224451/discussion-on-answer-by-expressjs123-use-javascript-to-import-a-json-file).